# Room SQL Query with COUNT(*) AS

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I having problem with SQL Query in Android Room. I have query as below

```
@Query("SELECT userId, COUNT(*) AS userCount FROM User " +
        "GROUP BY userId " +
        "ORDER BY userCount ASC")
List<UserCount> getUserAndCount();
```

But Android Studio shows `Cannot resolve symbol 'userCount'`. As above statement works fine in SQL, can you tell what's the problem in my code and how to use `AS` in Android Room?

Comment: Change your order to `Order BY Count(*) ASC` The problem not in your select but in order, the `userCount` declare in your select statement so where statement doesn't know who `userCount`

Comment: I have UserCount object that has element userCount. That's why I want to save it as userCount. I guess using Count(*) works, but I need to have custom naming.

Comment: Just sub query and order in your outer query..

Comment: It looks like aliases aren't supported in the `ORDER BY` clause.  Unexpected to me, but just repeat `COUNT(*)` in this case.

Comment: @dwir182 what do you mean by sub query? I suppose Room doesn't have such thing. Can you explain how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove alias from order by , you need to use COUNT(*) expression in order by cluase

```
@Query("SELECT userId, COUNT(*) AS userCount FROM User " +
        "GROUP BY userId " +
        "ORDER BY COUNT(*)")
List<UserCount> getUserAndCount();
```

Comment: That works, but I need to save with custom naming - "userCount". Because I have UserCount object that has element userCount.

Comment: it's already named userCount, just you need to remove the name userCount from order by cluase

Comment: oh yeah. Then how about if I need `COUNT(*)` multiple times within query, do I have to call `COUNT(*)` again and again? There is no way of saving as `userCount` and using it?

Comment: yes there is a way, in that case you need to use subquery

Comment: Can you share UserCount class, what fields does it contain?